# How to add another tab dynamically to bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a vertical tab with the dynamical addition of tab through a modal in Bootstrap3.

Also in each tab, we can able to edit the title of the tab or delete it easily.

Can it be possible through javascript or JQuery.

I have attached the image.

[image: Dynamic Tabs]

Comment: Your question is too generic, please provide a code example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

working example as below with custom code `javascript` and `jquery`

```js
var button='<button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button>';
var tabID = 1;
function resetTab(){
 var tabs=$("#tab-list li:not(:first)");
 var len=1
 $(tabs).each(function(k,v){
  len++;
  $(this).find('a').html('Tab ' + len + button);
 })
 tabID--;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn-add-tab').click(function() {
        tabID++;
        $('#tab-list').append($('<li><a href="#tab' + tabID + '" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span>Tab ' + tabID + '</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-muted edit"></span> <button class="close" type="button" title="Remove this page">×</button></a></li>'));
        $('#tab-content').append($('<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab' + tabID + '">Tab ' + tabID + ' content</div>'));
        $(".edit").click(editHandler);
    });
    
    $('#tab-list').on('click', '.close', function() {
        var tabID = $(this).parents('a').attr('href');
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
        $(tabID).remove();

        //display first tab
        var tabFirst = $('#tab-list a:first');
        resetTab();
        tabFirst.tab('show');
    });

    var list = document.getElementById("tab-list");
});

var editHandler = function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.css("visibility", "hidden");
  $(this).prev().attr("contenteditable", "true").focusout(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("contenteditable").off("focusout");
    t.css("visibility", "visible");
  });
};

$(".edit").click(editHandler);
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: solid 1px lightgreen;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>
                <button id="btn-add-tab" type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Add Tab</button>
            </p>
            <!-- Nav tabs -->
            <ul id="tab-list" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><span>Tab 1 </span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil text-muted edit"></span></a></li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Tab panes -->
            <div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">Tab 1 content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly.. :)

Comment: Can we add button to remove under the tab ? If i am doing its not able to close the tab itself.